# How do I call a static Typescript class function from javascript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a ts script (`test.ts`) something like this:

```
class Foo {
    public static bar() {
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

and I want to call it from plain js like this (`test.html`):

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
    Foo.bar();
</script>
```

`test.html` is placed in the same directory as `test.js`, which is compiled and integrated by webpack.

Is this possible? If so, how should I do it?

**UPDATE**

Okay so I changed the program like so:

```
class Foo {
    public bar() {
        console.log("test");
    }
}
```

But still, the javascript can't find the `Foo` class.

Comment: How about trying it out? You can also use the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html) to see the difference between static and non-static functions.

Comment: *"But still no chance"* what does that mean? You showed what you have, what happenned? Errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your question:

in your **test.ts**:

```
class Foo {
    public static bar() {
        console.log("test");
    }
}
window.Foo = Foo;
```

in your **test html**:

```
<script src="test.js"></script>
<script>
    Foo.bar();
</script>
```

Your typescript compiler probably use closure when compiling, so everything is closed in a scope of an anonymous function:

```
(function(){
    ...
})()
```

So to have access to your function from html, you should assign it to window.

---

But if you are doing simple things, you don't really need TypeScript, stay with vanilla JavaScript. You can use ES6 classes if you want.

TypeScript is used for more complex solutions. In TypeScript you should use export & imports between files, not assigning to window...

Comment: Thank you! I'll also look into exports as well. The sample is simple, but I need my code to work in an ES5 environment + it's going to be a little more complex in the inside, so I thought I'd use Typescript. Thanks again!