# How to call typescript class function from inline onclick

Tags: javascript, html, typescript

I have typescript class that look like this:

```
class Handler {
    log () {
        console.log('logged!');
    }

    detectEvents() {
       
        let allElementsWithInlineEvents = this._findElementsWithArributePrefix('*', 'on');//[element, element]
        //some code for getting element attributes...
       
        if(attribute.name.startsWith('on')){            
            attribute.value = "log();"
        }
    }
}
```

I can see in the dom that `log()` function added to inline onclick, but when I click nothing happen, It's like he didn't know what is 'log' function.
I'm compiling Typescript using rollup.

Any ideas why it is now working or how can I fix it

Comment: The javascript doesn't know the function log() as it's within the class. Have you tried adding an eventlistener to the element instead?

Comment: Also, you could try something like https://stackoverflow.com/a/49056389/5706942
So you have window.CustomHandler = Handler. Then the click event will call CustomHandler.log()

Comment: Yeah addeventlistener will be much easier, but in that case I need specifically to intercept inline clicks. The link you posted in the second comment solved the problem!